# One function performing two methods

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to understand what happens in this java method `s.split(" ").length`. In the sense that it does two things.

The split method returns an array, does the length get called on that? If so would the inner function always execute first ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what happens. `s.split()` returns an array, and `.length` dereferences the returned array. `.split()` _has_ to be evaluated first, because otherwise `.length` would have nothing to dereference. (chained methods will generally evaluate from left to right on each others' returned values - in other words, `s.split(" ").length` is the same as `(s.split(" ")).length`)

Comment: I don't think there's an "inner function" however.  It's just order of operations.  It executes left to right.  First `split` is called, then `length` is called.

Comment: The array returned by split() is then LOST after the execution of the line. I'd venture to say that most of the time you'd want to use that array somehow in your code. It's probably a better idea to write it out in separate lines as demonstrated in the post by Mad Physicist.

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation chains left-to-right. Writing out the steps with temporary variables helps you see the intermediate types:

```
String s = "a b c";
String[] parts = s.split(" ");
int n = parts.length;
```